# FOP/AEM: Deserialization not allowed for class org.apache.fop.fonts.FontCache

Tags: osgi, aem, apache-fop, aem-6

Unable to get external font in fop, getting message:

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Deserialization not allowed for class org.apache.fop.fonts.FontCache (on Thu Nov 15 11:07:35 PST 2018)
        at org.kantega.notsoserial.DefaultNotSoSerial.preventDeserialization(DefaultNotSoSerial.java:256)
        at org.kantega.notsoserial.DefaultNotSoSerial.onBeforeResolveClass(DefaultNotSoSerial.java:248)
        at org.kantega.notsoserial.ObjectInputStreamClassVisitor.onBeforeResolveClass(ObjectInputStreamClassVisitor.java:48)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1868)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2042)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
        at org.apache.fop.fonts.FontCache.loadFrom(FontCache.java:151)
        at org.apache.fop.fonts.FontCache.load(FontCache.java:132)
        at org.apache.fop.fonts.FontManager.setUseCache(FontManager.java:121)
        at org.apache.fop.fonts.FontManager.(FontManager.java:63)
        at org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory$1.(FopFactory.java:159)
        a.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Deserialization not allowed for class org.apache.fop.fonts.FontCachet org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.(FopFactory.java:156)
        at org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.newInstance(FopFactory.java:177)
        at com.intelsecurity.aem.services.impl.util.PDFFOPServiceImpl.createPDF(PDFFOPServiceImpl.java:74)
        at com.intelsecurity.aem.services.impl.checkout.CreatePurchaseReceiptDataServiceImpl.createPurchaseReceiptData(CreatePurchaseReceiptDataServiceImpl.java:172)
        at com.intelsecurity.aem.servlets.checkout.PurchaseOrderServlet.operationGetOrderSummary(PurchaseOrderServlet.java:342)
        at com.intelsecurity.aem.servlets.checkout.PurchaseOrderServlet.doPost(PurchaseOrderServlet.java:178)
        at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet.mayService(SlingAllMethodsServlet.java:146)
        at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:342)
        at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:374)
        at

Following is by fopconfig file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<fop version="1.0">
  <base>.</base>
  <source-resolution>72</source-resolution>
  <target-resolution>72</target-resolution>
  <default-page-settings height="11.00in" width="8.50in"/>
  <renderers>
    <renderer mime="application/pdf">
      <filterList>
        <value>flate</value>
      </filterList>
      <fonts>
         <font embed-url=".">
          <font-triplet name="TrueType" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
        </font>
      </fonts>
    </renderer>
  </renderers>
</fop>
```

and my font is kept is the same folders as fop-config

To fix the above issue, I tried the following step:

```
final FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
            fopFactory.getFontManager().getFontCache().clear();
```

however, my osgi bundle seems to be still in installed state.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AEM uses a deserialization firewall and only explicitly white-listed classes are allowed to be de-serialized. you need to white-list your class in the osgi configuration for - `com.adobe.cq.deserfw.impl.DeserializationFirewallImpl`

[image: serialization firewall config]